# Run code each time screen is turned ON (not unlocked) - even when app is killed

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver

I asked this question before but was reported as DUPLICATE. However, the suggested post did not answer my question. So, I'm trying again and making myself clearer.

I am trying to develop an app that can change the wallpaper every time the user clicks the power/home button when the device is locked (kinda like the Samsung Lock Screen Wallpaper library). So, each time the screen goes from black to light, the wallpaper changes.

I read that this can somewhat be achieved using action_screen_on. However, it is said that this intent can only be used if the app in running. I would want the wallpaper to change even when the app is killed.

This is a snippet of my code:

```
public class screenOnReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON)) {
            WallpaperManager myWallpaperManager = WallpaperManager.getInstance(context);

            int height = 500;
            int width = 500;
            Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
            Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
            Paint paintGradient = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
            Shader shader = new LinearGradient(0, 0, width, height,
                    new int[]{0xffffff, 0x454545}, null, Shader.TileMode.CLAMP);

            paintGradient.setShader(shader);
            canvas.drawRect(0, 0, width, height, paintGradient);
            try {
                myWallpaperManager.setBitmap(bitmap);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.v("Error", "Problem setting wallpaper");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I don't see anything. It is as if this BroadcastReceiver was not fired at all.
Thank you in advance folks.

Comment: I do not believe that what you want is possible on Android 8.0+, at least without root.

Comment: Oh I see. I use a Samsung S10. And, there is a wallpaper setting in the Samsung Galaxy wallpaper library that changes the wallpaper every time I click the power button when the screen is locked. Do they have an advantage since they manufactured the device? :)

Comment: Yes. Samsung can do what Samsung wants with Samsung devices. It is possible that Samsung exposes a supported API that you can use on Samsung devices. However, on the whole, Google is trying to stop the notion of apps doing things based on common Android system events, like the screen turning on, because too many apps try doing things on those events.

Comment: Yes i think so since these apps are preinstalled these apps have access to private apis which are not available to normal developer

Comment: Thank you very much. Only now do I realize that manufacturers can have APIs available only to them and not for the use of normal developers. Thank you very much again folks.

Comment: Hi there. I am actually aware of that. I have an app in the Play Store called dy/dx that generates gradient wallpapers. :)